How to prevent keyboard and trackpad to wake up Mac from Sleep?
I have removed the screen on my Macbook 2019 16 inch (Intel) device, because my LCD was damaged, so I decided to just use an external screen. However, the problem I am facing now is, when I put the MBP in the bag while it is sleeping, sometimes there is pressure which causes the keyboard to be clicked, and wake up the  MBP from sleep or shutdown.
Is there a way to disable the keyboard or trackpad to wake up the Mac from sleep? I just want to turn on the Mac from the power button only.
Thank you in advance.

There is no Apple supported way of disabling the keyboard and mouse from waking macOS.
Consider finding or making a solid case for transporting the device. A 3D printed overlay to protect the keys is another possibility.

What about this: Sudo nvram AutoBoot=%00 method? So its just prevent auto boot when screen lid open?

Have you tried it? Does it affect the behaviour of the keyboard and mouse?

no, it's not working
